# MongoDB : Arrays or not?

Tags: mongodb

I am storing some data into a mongo database and I'm not sure about the structure I have to use... It's about IoT sensors that sends a value (temperature, pression, etc...) every specific time. I want to store into a collection (the collection name will be the sensor name) all the value from the sensor for a specific time (I thought about an array), the sensor type (like temperature).

Here is an example :

```
{
    history : [ { date : "ISODate(2016-02-01T11:23:21.321Z)", value : 10.232216 }, { date : "ISODate(2016-02-01T11:26:41.314Z)", value : 10.164892 } ],
    type : "temperature"
}
```

But my problem is that I want to query the database to get the history as a "list" of document. Each one with the date and the value.
On the other hand, I want to add a new value to the history each time there is a new one.

Thanks

Comment: If the values you plan on storing in an array is going to end up growing very big, You are better off making it, its own collection.

Answer (score 2):

Store every reading in a readings collection like:

```
{
    date : "ISODate(2016-02-01T11:23:21.321Z)", 
    value : 10.232216, 
    type : "temperature",
    sensor-name: "sensor-1"
}
```

This way you can access readings by type, date, value AND sensor. There is no reason why you would need to create a collection for each sensor.

Comment: I guess you could make a collection for each sensor, though it doesn't really make anything faster if you index things properly.

Comment: But this way, I will be storing the type in each documents. Isn't this a bit redundant and memory waste ?

Comment: Physical storage memory is cheap, time isn't. Generally when you are building a database structure you will always prioritize read/write time over memory. The whole concept of indexing in databases is basically using memory space to speed up access times.

Comment: Isn't there a way to bind a document value to another collection ?

Comment: You could used a shared index between two collections, but I don't see why you would need something like that.

Comment: Ok, so I have to figure out first what will be the most executed queries to build up a good db structure ? You are saying there is no use to create a collection for each sensor, is it also for read time performance ? If i have a unique collection for all the values from all sensors, it will be massive :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102248/discussion-between-ting-sun-and-phoste).

Answer (score 2):

[Ting Suns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35131468/2604949) is absolutely appropriate: Just store each measurement reading as a separate document in a collection. In doing so it's up to you if you want to arrange a separate collection for each sensor. Although putting them all into the same collection seems to be more obvious.

Especially you should not store items - in your case measurement readings - whose number is basically infinitely growing or could become "very large" into an embedded array of another MongoDB document. This is because:

- The [size of an individual document is limited to 16MB (MongoDB Version 3.2)](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)
- Often recurring modifications of the parent document could be inefficient for the memory management of the database engine.

Furthermore queries for individual embedded items/measurements are inefficient and more difficult to implement because you would actually have to query for the entire parent document.

Answer (score 0):

How you divide readings into collections is completely up to you, whether one collection or multiple. And there are likely good arguments to be had on both sides.

However, regarding arrays: Just remember that sensor readings are *unbounded*. That is, they are possibly infinite in nature - just a flow of readings. MongoDB documents are limited in size (currently 16MB). With unbounded arrays, you will eventually hit this limit, which will result in failed updates, and requiring you to alter your storage architecture to accommodate your sensor readings.

So... you either need to devise a sharding solution to split array data across multiple documents (to avoid document-size-limit issues), or avoid arrays and store readings in separate documents.